# Local machines Virtual hosts redirect to web server root

Tags: php, apache, vhosts

I am trying to setup Virtual Hosts for a project on my Mac, I have done this before at work with no problems so I am guessing there is a config file somewhere that is causing the issue, could anyone tell me the files I should be checking for issues like this, for testing I have created the following in:

FILE: /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1 test.co.uk
```

FILE: /etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost localhost:80>
<Directory "/Users/ric/Sites/test">
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
   AllowOverride all
       Order Deny,Allow
       Allow from all
</Directory>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/ric/Sites/test"
    ServerName test.co.uk
</VirtualHost>
```

The test directory exists and has an index.php with

```
<?php echo "Test";
```

But I am always redirected to the web server root /Users/ric/Sites

I have looked in phps error log which has nothing as it isn't technically an error, apaches access_log has nothing related.

I would appreciate a pointer in the right direction for config files that could be causing this..

I can post my httpd.conf and php.ini if this would help..?

Or is there a way to clean install PHP, remove all current config and start again? As I feel like I am looking for a needle in the haystack.

Regards
Ric

Comment: Did you restart apache after adding vhost?

Comment: yes I did restart apache after adding

Comment: Try renaming your vhost declaration from `<VirtualHost localhost:80>` to `<VirtualHost *:80>` or `<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>`

Comment: Tried this and restarted apache after each change, no difference

Comment: What is the apache version @RGregson?

Comment: Server version: Apache/2.4.16 (Unix)
Server built:   Jul 22 2015 21:03:09

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

`Order Deny,Allow
 Allow from all`

use

`Require all granted`

then restart apache

Comment: I tried that still no difference made, still redirects to root